# Git4Idea plugin not taking advantage of the git index

Tags: git, intellij-idea

The Git4Idea plugin automatically adds changes to the index even with the [improved git support](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/version_control.html#Git_support) in the new Intellij IDEA version 8.1.

There's even a post on the Jetbrains forum about this [issue](http://www.jetbrains.net/devnet/thread/277569) without any replies.

According to [Embracing the Git Index](http://www.jdl.com/papers/Embrace_The_Git_Index.pdf) Linus Torvalds once said "If you deny the Index, you really deny git itself."

If you want to use Git the way it was meant to be used you have to disable the plugin and revert to using git as an external tool or from the command line.

How are you dealing with the quirks of the abstracted git interface?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't really had problems with this behavior from git4idea.

While in theory, the power of the index is useful, in practice I rarely want to check in only a subset of my changes.  When I need to, I can do that in intellij by unchecking the files that I don't want to commit and git4idea manages that transparently.

that said - I do a lot of git operations on the command line regardless and just rely on Intellij to provide me information about what I've changed in a file while I am working with it.

Your question is kind of open ended.  What 'quirks' in particular are you having problems with?

Comment: What I meant by 'quirks' was the dumbing down of Git to work like CVS, Subversion, etc.

Here's an example of using the power of the git index to make clean commits: http://tomayko.com/writings/the-thing-about-git